# Dynamically parse data into XML based on XSD

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xsd

I am trying to build an Excel addon which would be able to read data from an excel spreadsheet and automatically parse data into an XML file in a consistent manner. I have an Extremely simple example (which does not incorporate good XSD design) However my intention is to find a tool which can be used to marshal this info. 
essentially the excel user would be able to customise the column names to populate information about any elements defined within the XSD definition.

- The spreadsheet specifies the root element Name From Column A3 down.
- and should expect child elements of the root as specified by Fields B1:F1
- each of the elements will have an attribute as specified by fields B2:F2
- values for the attributes are shown in green

[image]

Is it possible to dynamically marshal an xml based on a defined xsd? I am looking for any java parser which could handle this?

sample xsd would be something like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="Person">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="PN"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name"
                                  type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PF"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Phone"
                                  type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PA"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Address"
                                  type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="PO"
                        minOccurs="0"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attribute name="Order"
                                  type="xs:int" />
                    <xs:attribute name="OrderDate"
                                  type="xs:date" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: JAXB is just about as good as it gets for marshaling xml data. Many features of JAXB come packaged with the JDK now (>=1.6). If you need to deal directly with the XSD you can use XSOM https://xsom.java.net/ but that library is very complex and documentation/examples are hard to come by. I would take a good hard look at JAXB before you go to much further, theres lots of great resources for it.

Comment: What I also was asking, is if there are any native methods that would automatically know which attributes are accociated with the elements so that you could do something like person.PN("name") = "tom" where name would be injected from the excel sheet and the parser would see that name is an attribute of PN